# Selecting and Deselecting UITableViewCells - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

Currently I am able to tap a cell and select it using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. However, I am unable to deselect it when tapped. I wish to toggle these two features.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

- I have a `TableView` in my `View Controller`.
- The `dataSource` and `delegate` are already set up.
- Multiple selection is enabled in `UIBuilder` for the table.

Comment: In this code what are you trying to do? You get the currently tapped cell and then set the backgroundColor to purple. What is its purpose and is it working?

Comment: Yes, I get the currently tapped cell and set the background to purple and it is working well. Now, I am trying to tap on that cell again and deselect it to the way it was before I selected it.

Answer (score 8):

I could have sworn I tried this before and it didn't work then.

I decided to use two functions..

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()        
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    deselectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: Bloody hell, mate! Thanks a million. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to create a simple bool and verify in the next tap. If its true you use the code bellow else you keep it tapped until you tap it again

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code Syntax for Swift 3 / 4

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
     currentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
     currentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 }
```